# NSolve - Problem with univariate long polynomial

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

Below I am trying to find the steady state of x1 (x2 is a func of x1) in terms of a variable q1. `x1stst`. Then I wish to compute q1 values giving "trace = 0"  in `equq1` (equq1 includes x1 steady states as a function of q1). Unfortunately `NSolve` doesn't work due to the hideous polynomial of `equq1`

```
(*Find q1*)
q2 = 46.2857;
q3 = 0.111;
q4 = 5.714285714285714`;
q5 = 0.14285714285714288`;
NSolve[q1 q2  (q3 + x1)/(1 + x1) x2 - (q4 x1)/(q5 + x1) == 0 && 
   1/(1 + x1^2) - x2 == 0, {x1, x2}];
x1stst = NSolve[
   q1 q2 (q3 + x1)/(1 + x1) 1/(1 + x1^2) - (q4 x1)/(q5 + x1) == 0, x1];
equq1 = -1 + (5.714285714285714` x1)/(0.14285714285714288` + x1)^2 - 
   5.714285714285714`/(0.14285714285714288` + x1) - (
   46.285714285714285` (0.111` + x1) x2 q1)/(1 + x1)^2 + (
   46.285714285714285` x2 q1)/(1 + x1);
NSolve[equq1 == 0 /. 
   x1stst[[1]] /. {x2 -> 1/(1 + x1stst[[1]]^2)}, q1, Reals]
```

I tried `Together` `Collect` etc. non of them worked. Looked similar questions but again  couldn't find anything.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `x1stst[[1]]` is a replacement rule. An expression like: `x2 -> 1/(1 + x1stst[[1]]^2)` does not make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

(*Find q1*)
q2 = 46.2857 // Rationalize;
q3 = 0.111 // Rationalize;
q4 = 5.714285714285714` // Rationalize;
q5 = 0.14285714285714288` // Rationalize;
```

Restrict `x1` to Reals

```
x1stst = Solve[q1 q2 (q3 + x1)/(1 + x1) 1/(1 + x1^2) - (q4 x1)/(q5 + x1) == 0,
     x1, Reals] // Simplify;

equq1 = -1 + (5.714285714285714` x1)/(0.14285714285714288` + x1)^2 - 
    5.714285714285714`/(0.14285714285714288` + 
       x1) - (46.285714285714285` (0.111` + x1) x2 q1)/(1 + 
        x1)^2 + (46.285714285714285` x2 q1)/(1 + x1) // Rationalize // 
  FullSimplify

(* -1 - 40/(1 + 7 x1)^2 + (10287 q1 x2)/(250 (1 + x1)^2) *)
```

`x1stst` is a rule an cannot be used in an expression such as `{x2 -> 1/(1 + x1stst[[1]]^2)}`

```
f[q1_] = (equq1 /. x1stst[[1, 1]]) /. {x2 -> 
      1/(1 + (x1 /. x1stst[[1, 1]])^2)} // N[#, 20] &;

(sol = NSolve[f[q1] == 0, q1, Reals, WorkingPrecision -> 20]) // N

(* {{q1 -> 0.763707}} *)
```

Comment: Thank you! is these claims true:1-"Rationalize" makes the code faster due to memory issues 2-  from the beginning one needs to restrict variables to Reals-not just the end solution-. ```x1stst[[1, 1]]``` is great, didn't know that.

Comment: In  ...```N[#, 20] &;``` why u need the ```&```? When you write  ```N[#, 20]```doesn't guarantee ```WorkingPrecision -> 20``` if not why?

Comment: (1) `Rationalize` generally makes the code slower; however, it may enable simplification which improves precision and any simplification would help the speed. (2) It is better to use any known constraints/assumptions throughout. (3) The `&` is needed to close a pure function using `Slot` (i.e., `#`). `N[#, 20]` is meaningless without the closing `&`. (4) `N[#, 20]&` will only guarantee `WorkingPrecision -> 20` if all parts of the input have precision of at least `20`. For example, compare `Precision[N[0.5, 20]]` with `Precision[N[0.5//Rationalize, 20]]`

Answer (score 1):

If you assume `x2 -> 1/(1 + x1^2)` ContourPlot shows possible solutions

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate[0 == q1 q2 (q3 + x1)/(1 + x1) x2 - (q4 x1)/(q5 + x1) /.x2 -> 1/(1 + x1^2)], {x1, -10, 10}, {q1, -5, 5},FrameLabel -> {x1, q1}]
```

[image]

Comment: That is so great :D thank you!

Comment: @confused  You're welcome, hope it helps!